# Not understanding steps in Algebraic simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The simplification in question is that the expression goes from $(4-x)(6-x)(3-x)-8(3-x)=0$,    to    $(3-x)(8-x)(2-x)=0$

I don't understand how one goes from the first expression to the second. I tried factoring out $(3-x)$ but didn't get very far, it doesn't seem to be the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the first equation and by putting $(3-x)$ as a common factor we get

$$(3-x)\left((4-x)(6-x)-8\right)=0$$
Now we develop the second factor and simplify we get

$$(4-x)(6-x)-8=x^2-10x+16$$
finally we factor the last expression 
$$x^2-10x+16=(x-2)(x-8)$$
and we conclude.

Comment: Thank you, I should've kept pushing in that direction, I didn't think they would've skipped so many steps.

Comment: You're welcome.